# Infinite viewpager with only one item for Android

Tags: android, animation, android-viewpager, slideshow

How to create an infinite viewpager, but with only one view? For example, I want to scroll the view to the left, then update it and show the same view from the right. I need to see cool animation, with dragging view under the finger, not just to detect the gesture and slide out. I also need to understand in which direction the scroll happened.

Please help!

Comment: `viewpager` seems a bit overkill for it . Just use basic `TranslationAnimation` on the `View` There are bunch of options to from u can use `MotionLayout` for instance.